Illegal touching within 5yards
Could anyone explain exactly what the NFL Rule 8 Section 4 Article 2 means to me?

The NFL rule 8.4.1: "...so long as the receiver has not moved beyond a point that is even with the defender"?
And I don't understand entirely the NFL rule 8.4.2.

Rule 8.4.2: https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-rulebook/#article-2-illegal-contact-within-five-yards

These rules detail how the defense may make contact to hinder an eligible receiver.
In the five-yard zone, a defender can use his hands to shove the receiver.  But if the receiver is able to move in a way that he is able to pass the defender and be more downfield, the defender may no longer contact the receiver.
To be even with the defender means the receiver and the defender are both the same distance from the line of scrimmage.   Once the receiver is past that point, contact would be illegal.
8.4.2 lists the ways that you can get a foul for illegal contact:

Touching eligible receiver outside the zone
Initial touch of the receiver is in the back
Continuing contact after the receiver moves further downfield than the defender
If contact with the receiver in the zone is broken, touching the receiver again

